# BGE: What objects are Game Properties?

Tags: python, game-engine

This and/or how to access and change them in a script.

If you use the .getPropertyNames()-function of an object it only provides you with a list of the names of the properties. How can one actually change them?

Also you could use a property actuator with the python controller but the property and python controller are on 2 different objects.
So it is about changing game properties of another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the object like a dictionary to access and change properties

```
# Access
print (object['propertyname'])

# Change
object['propertyname'] = 4
```

Comment: @Jonathan, see, I was right

Comment: Thanks a lot! I probably could not have found that out by googling and checking the documentation.